# what means return { someObject : someObject }

Tags: javascript

I saw this code, after looking for a while and look for on the internet I still do not get it.

```
var client = function (){  

    var engine = {  

        ie: 0,  
        gecko: 0,  
        webkit: 0,  
        version: null  

    };

    return {  
        engine : engine  
    };  
}();
```

My specific question is about the return statement. I know that:

`client` is a function that `var engine = { ... }` is creating a object engine with some properties inside and a default values, but I do not understand the `return` and why at the of the function it has `()`.

Answer (score 2):

This expression the variable `client` is being assigned to is both

1. Defining a function which returns an object expression
2. Invoking that function and using the result as the new value for `client`

A more long winded way of writing that code is

```
var method = function(){  
    var engine = {  

        ie: 0,  
        gecko: 0,  
        webkit: 0,  
        version: null  

    };

    return {  
        engine : engine  
    };  
};
var client = method();
```

Answer (score 0):

The inner function is returning an associative array (a dictionary, if you will) where the key `engine` maps to the `engine` variable. The "engine" before the colon is the dictionary key and is treated as text rather than a variable. It might be clearer to look at it as

```
return {  
    "engine" : engine  
};
```

which works identically.

So, after this code runs, you can access `client.engine` and that will get you the "engine" that was built in the internal function.

Comment: An Object more precisely, with property keys and values. There are no associative arrays in javascript!

Answer (score 0):

It creates an object `client` that looks like this:

```
Object
    engine: Object
        gecko: 0
        ie: 0
        version: null
        webkit: 0
```

I think it's written to illustrate some points about JavaScript, because it could be simpler written:

```
var client = {
     engine: {
         ie: 0,  
         gecko: 0,  
         webkit: 0,  
         version: null
     }
};
```